# How to pass class to twig custom tag using twig extension Node compiler

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony6

Factory creation with injected entity repository

```
namespace App\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use App\Factory\EntityFactoryRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class EntityFactoryPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        if (!$container->has(EntityFactoryRegistry::class)) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->findDefinition(EntityFactoryRegistry::class);
        $taggedServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('app.entity_factory');
        $entityManager = $container->findDefinition('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        foreach ($taggedServices as $id => $tags) {
            $definition->addMethodCall('addFactory', [new Reference($id), $entityManager]);
        }
    }
} 

//using code like this to get factory for entity, now this part works, I have the factory accessible everywhere I want.
foreach ((new \ReflectionClass($this::class))->getAttributes(Access::class) as $attribute) {
    if (key_exists('entity', $attribute->getArguments())) {
        $this->factory = $this->entityFactoryRegistry->get($attribute->getArguments()['entity']);
    }
}
```

Post factory:

```
<?php

namespace App\Factory;

use App\Command\EntityCommandInterface;
use App\Command\PostCommand;
use App\Entity\Base\BaseEntity;
use App\Entity\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\Autoconfigure;

#[Autoconfigure(tags: ['app.entity_factory'])]
class PostFactory implements EntityFactoryInterface
{
    private ?EntityManagerInterface $entityManager = null;

    public function create(EntityCommandInterface|PostCommand $command): BaseEntity
    {

    }

    public function edit(BaseEntity|Post $entity, EntityCommandInterface|PostCommand $command): BaseEntity
    {

    }

    public function getMainPosts (): array
    {
        return $this->entityManager->getRepository($this->getEntity())
            ->findAll();
    }

    public function setEntityManager (EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): void
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getEntity(): string
    {
        return Post::class;
    }
}
```

now when it comes to twig extension, I would like to get factory the same way and pass it to custom twig node.

Extension creation:

```
namespace App\Extension;

use App\Extension\Parser\FactoryTokenParser;
use App\Factory\EntityFactoryRegistry;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;

class FactoryExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function __construct(
        protected readonly EntityFactoryRegistry $entityFactoryRegistry,
    )
    {
    }

    public function getTokenParsers(): array
    {
        return [
            new FactoryTokenParser($this->entityFactoryRegistry),
        ];
    }
}
```

Token parser:

```
<?php

namespace App\Extension\Parser;

use App\Extension\Node\FactoryTagNode;
use App\Factory\EntityFactoryRegistry;
use Twig\Token;
use Twig\TokenParser\AbstractTokenParser;

class FactoryTokenParser extends AbstractTokenParser
{
    public function __construct(
        protected readonly EntityFactoryRegistry $entityFactoryRegistry,
    )
    {}

    public function parse(Token $token): FactoryTagNode
    {
        $stream = $this->parser->getStream();

        $entityClass = $this->parser->getExpressionParser()->parseExpression();

        if (!class_exists($entityClass->getAttribute("value"))) {
            throw new \Exception("Class provided to factory does not exist");
        }

        // Parse the content between {% factory %} and {% endfactory %}
        $stream->expect(Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);
        $body = $this->parser->subparse([$this, 'decideFactoryEndTag'], true);
        $stream->expect(Token::BLOCK_END_TYPE);

        $entityFactory = $this->entityFactoryRegistry->get($entityClass->getAttribute("value"));

        return new FactoryTagNode(
            $entityFactory,
            $body,
            $token->getLine(),
            $this->getTag()
        );
    }

    public function decideFactoryEndTag(Token $token): bool
    {
        return $token->test('endfactory');
    }

    public function getTag(): string
    {
        return 'factory';
    }
}
```

Node:

```
<?php

namespace App\Extension\Node;

use App\Factory\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Twig\Compiler;
use Twig\Node\Node;

class FactoryTagNode extends Node
{
    private EntityFactoryInterface $factory;

    public function __construct(EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory, Node $body, int $line, string $tag)
    {
        parent::__construct(['body' => $body], [], $line, $tag);
        $this->factory = $entityFactory;
    }

    public function compile(Compiler $compiler): void
    {
        $body = $this->getNode('body');

        $compiler
            ->addDebugInfo($this)
            ->write(sprintf('$context["factory"] = %s;', $this->getVarExport($this->factory)))
            ->write('ob_start();' . PHP_EOL)
            ->subcompile($body)
            ->write('echo strtoupper(ob_get_clean());' . PHP_EOL);
    }

    private function getVarExport($var): ?string
    {
        return var_export($var, true);
    }
}
```

Now this is the part, where it wont work.
`->write(sprintf('$context["factory"] = %s;', $this->getVarExport($this->factory)))`
Error: An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("Warning: var_export does not handle circular references").

When I initialize class like this
`->write(sprintf('$context["factory"] = new %s();', get_class(this->factory)))`

Twig has the class available, but I want to inject the factory class, not to re-init new instance of a class for twig.

Why, reason is that, entity manager is injected into factories using compiler pass and when I re-init class, it is no longer available.

Are there more solutions to this I am unable to figure out?

Twig rendering part:

```
{% factory 'App\\Entity\\Post' %}
    {{ dump(factory.mainPosts) }}
{% endfactory %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, got it figured out, basically what I did

FactoryExtension.php:

- added getter, to get factory from collection, wont pass it any more to the parser.

```
<?php

namespace App\Extension;

use App\Extension\Parser\FactoryTokenParser;
use App\Factory\EntityFactoryRegistry;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class FactoryExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    public function __construct(
        protected readonly EntityFactoryRegistry $entityFactoryRegistry
    )
    {
    }

    public function getTokenParsers(): array
    {
        return [
            new FactoryTokenParser(),
        ];
    }

    public function getEntityFactory(string $className): ?object
    {
        return $this->entityFactoryRegistry->get($className);
    }
}
```

Main thing:
FactoryTagNode.php:

- since Environment is accessible from Twig Compiler, we can actually ask for registered extensions from it and access the methods inside of it.
- in my case $entityClass->getAttribute("value") === App\Entity\Post

```
<?php

namespace App\Extension\Node;

use Twig\Compiler;
use Twig\Node\Node;

class FactoryTagNode extends Node
{

    public function __construct(Node $entityClass, Node $body, int $line, string $tag)
    {
        parent::__construct(['entityClass' => $entityClass, 'body' => $body], [], $line, $tag);
    }

    public function compile(Compiler $compiler): void
    {
        $body = $this->getNode('body');
        $entityClass = $this->getNode('entityClass');

        $compiler
            ->addDebugInfo($this)
            ->write(sprintf('$context["factory"] = $this->env->getExtension(\'App\\Extension\\FactoryExtension\')->getEntityFactory(\'%s\');' . PHP_EOL, $entityClass->getAttribute("value")))
            ->write('ob_start();' . PHP_EOL)
            ->subcompile($body)
            ->write('echo strtoupper(ob_get_clean());' . PHP_EOL);
    }
}
```

And twig:

```
{% factory 'App\\Entity\\Post' %}
    {{ dump(factory.mainPosts|length) }} {# prints out 2 in my case #}
{% endfactory %}
```

Comment: Any reason you just didn't add a new `Twig\Function` inside your `FactoryExtension` to get the instance of the factory you wanted, e.g `{% set factory = get_factory('App\\Entity\\Post') %}`?

Comment: Yeah, that was another solution i thought about, but i want the factory to be injected without me writing extra code for it :) I also have custom Access attribute, which holds the entity name and i can actually get the attribute value from request and i dont even have to pass the entity name through template any more, my goal is to write as less code as possible and as dynamically as possible, while keeping the code clean :)